# MYSQL Multi-table delete when one of the tables does NOT contain a row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the following MYSQL to delete records from two different tables:

```
DELETE rfw_leaguepos, rfw_events 
FROM rfw_leaguepos 
INNER JOIN rfw_events 
ON rfw_events.official = rfw_leaguepos.fk_official 
WHERE rfw_leaguepos.fk_official = 11 && rfw_leaguepos.league = 1
```

Everything works fine if both the rfw_leaguepos and rfw_events table contain a row.  I would like for it to delete from both tables row or not.

I really appreciate everyone's help.  Thank you!!

Comment: You need separate queries for each table.

Comment: I don't think you should use JOIN for that (maybe CROSS JOIN would work though). I use seperate queries inside multi_query()

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: try the `OR` operator rather than the `AND` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out!!  I changed my query from an INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  This seems to be working.

```
 DELETE rfw_leaguepos, rfw_events FROM rfw_leaguepos LEFT OUTER JOIN rfw_events ON rfw_events.official = rfw_leaguepos.fk_official WHERE rfw_leaguepos.fk_official = 11 && rfw_leaguepos.league = 1
```